# WMI optimization

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have the following script.

```
$script:WMIClassNames = `
"CIM_Processor",`
"CIM_PhysicalMemory",`
"Win32_ComputerSystem",`
"CIM_BIOSElement",`
"Win32_OperatingSystem",`
"Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration",`
"Win32_Volume",`
"Win32_QuickFixEngineering",`
"CIM_Process",`
"WIN32_Service",`
"WIN32_NTLogEvent"

$script:WMIClassInfo = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $script:strSysName -Namespace "Root/CIMV2" -List | Select Name | Where-Object {$script:WMIClassNames -contains $_.Name}
```

When i measure the time of the script, it is taking almost 4 to 10 min to execute this script on remote machines. Can this script be optimized so that the execution time can be reduced?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Filter left, format right" rule may help.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.windowspowershell.aspx

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this script? All it will do is return the list of WMI classes you have given it (all of the classes are standard: they won't be somehow be missing on the remote system).

Comment: i am doing that only. i am checking if the WMI is not corrupt and the classes required by the script are present in the server. if the class is not present in the server, i will not at all execute the total script block associated with the query.

Comment: @bahrep, get-wmiobject dont have any filter option so that i can move the filtering to left.

Comment: Are you running the scrip on your box and communication with the other computer over the network ? If you try this , run the script directly on the remote machine and check the results if its fast then it is  the way the communications works over the networks so we can try change your script to use PowerShell Remoting  and speed stuff up for you. Let me know your results

Comment: @justinf I had the same thought. I ran `Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root/CIMV2" -List` on my local machine and it completed in less than a second. Executing on the remote machine via `Invoke-Command` and filtering the results there should speed things up significantly.